# CSS englarge grid image on hover, but move all other images around it out of the way

Tags: html, css

That's the best way I can explain it. I have a grid of images, and when I hover over one image it scales up. I want to make it so that all of the other images around the enlarged image sort of 'shift' or glide out of the way when this happens, in kind of a bubble effect.

Thanks!

```css
#photos {
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7%;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 5px;
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

#photos img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.13);
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="photos">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/300" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/300" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/300" />
</section>
```

Of course there is more to the html code, but it's just a grid of images, and that is the full css code for it.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS. Without it, we are just guessing. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @disinfor Okay, I added the code. The html is just a grid of images, but the css code I added exactly what is in my project. Thanks.